# How do I convert Byte Array response from WebClient to Xml?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am calling a third party service and they send the response as Xml. However, as I am using WebClient to call the service the response I get is a byte array.

```
var client = new WebClient();
var result = client.UploadValues(post_url, data);
```

result is a byte array. How do I convert it to XML to read the response given by the third party service?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `MemoryStream`:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(result))
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Just adding that XDocument over here is not from System.Xml.Linq namespace http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx but a normal Xml document which can be loaded into from the memory stream as shown here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tolong/archive/2007/11/15/read-write-xml-in-memory-stream.aspx

Answer (score 10):

You can turn the bytes into a string:

```
string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
```

and then parse it :

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```